# ¿En python 3 y Pandas, como agregar datos de un diccionario a un dataFrame, solo si no existen?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

En mi Script de Python he generado un diccionario con varios datos, los cuales quiero agregar a un archivo CSV, solo si las claves del diccionario no existen dentro del archivo, o que si existen entonces se sobre escriban para que no se dupliquen.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto utilizando pandas?

mi script ya es capaz de agregar los datos al dataFrame, pero me duplica los datos.

```
data_dict = {'2018mbusasalesjan': [0, '2018mbusasalesjan', 2018, 'January', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesfeb': [1, '2018mbusasalesfeb', 2018, 'February', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesmar': [2, '2018mbusasalesmar', 2018, 'March', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesapr': [3, '2018mbusasalesapr', 2018, 'April', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesmay': [4, '2018mbusasalesmay', 2018, 'May', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesjun': [5, '2018mbusasalesjun', 2018, 'June', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesjul': [6, '2018mbusasalesjul', 2018, 'July', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesaug': [7, '2018mbusasalesaug', 2018, 'August', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalessep': [8, '2018mbusasalessep', 2018, 'September', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesoct': [9, '2018mbusasalesoct', 2018, 'October', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesnov': [10, '2018mbusasalesnov', 2018, 'November', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2018mbusasalesdec': [11, '2018mbusasalesdec', 2018, 'December', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

datos_Sales_Mbusa =pd.read_csv('mbusasales.csv', index_col = 0, encoding = 'utf-8')
datos_Sales_Mbusa.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))
num_datos = int(datos_Sales_Mbusa['indice'].count())
datos_Sales_Mbusa.index = range(datos_Sales_Mbusa.shape[0])
indice_archivo = list(datos_Sales_Mbusa.indice)
llaves = data_dict.keys()
nuevo_Valor = num_datos+1
valores = list(data_dict.values())
for i, valor in enumerate(valores):
        nuevo_valor = int(nuevo_Valor)+i
        datos_Sales_Mbusa.loc[int(nuevo_valor)]= [valor[1], valor[2], valor[3], valor[4], valor[5], valor[6], valor[7], valor[8], valor[9],
                  valor[10], valor[11], valor[12], valor[13],valor[14] ]
datos_Sales_Mbusa.to_csv('mbusasales.csv',  encoding = 'utf-8',)
```

El archivo 'mbusasales.csv contiene los siguientes datos:

```
,indice,year,month,brocc conv,caulif conv,br spr,Sugar Snap Peas,Yellow Sq,Green Zucch,Brocc Org,Caulif Org,Carrots Org,Corn Org,Edamame Org
0,2018mbusasalesjan,2018,January,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,2018mbusasalesfeb,2018,February,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,2018mbusasalesmar,2018,March,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,2018mbusasalesapr,2018,April,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4,2018mbusasalesmay,2018,May,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
5,2018mbusasalesjun,2018,June,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
6,2018mbusasalesjul,2018,July,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
7,2018mbusasalesaug,2018,August,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
8,2018mbusasalessep,2018,August,350,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
9,2018mbusasalesoct,2018,October,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
10,2018mbusasalesnov,2018,November,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11,2018mbusasalesdec,2018,December,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12,2017mbusasalesjan,2017,January,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
13,2017mbusasalesfeb,2017,February,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
14,2017mbusasalesmar,2017,March,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
15,2017mbusasalesapr,2017,April,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
16,2017mbusasalesmay,2017,May,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
17,2017mbusasalesjun,2017,June,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
18,2017mbusasalesjul,2017,July,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
19,2017mbusasalesaug,2017,August,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
20,2017mbusasalessep,2017,August,350,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
21,2017mbusasalesoct,2017,October,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
22,2017mbusasalesnov,2017,November,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

La columna que indica si los datos ya están en el archivo csv es 'indice' y en el diccionario es la clave. Si se comparan los datos del diccionario con los del archivo, te puedes dar cuenta que estos indices ya están en el archivo, por lo tanto se deben sobre escribir.

Comment: Un CSV al ser un archivo secuencial sin ningún tipo de índice no se suele "actualizar", o se "agrega" información o se sobreescribe completamente. Lo que preguntas, creo que es más sencillo resolverlo desde pandas, te sugiero que agregues un ejemplo de código de lo que buscas, para que te podamos ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: @Patricio Moracho ya agregue el ejemplo y escribí más detalles. Saludos

Comment: Cómo dijo @PatricioMoracho anteriormente, lo normal es que proceses tu dataset en memoria y luego escribas los resultados por única vez en el archivo CSV como salida. Si tu dataset es muy grande, creo que estarías forzando un poco las cosas. Quizas un archivo CSV no sea la solución y debas utilizar un motor de base de datos.

Comment: Ademas sería bueno que te acostumbres a usar PEP8 (en otras palabras: la convención de estilos de Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de la base de que como se ha comentado lo que haces no es posiblemente lo más eficiente, puedes actualizar los datos cargando tanto el csv como el diccionario en sendos DataFrames, aplicar `pandas.concat` y luego eliminar los duplicados manteniendo las filas procedentes del diccionario:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {'2018mbusasalesjan': [0, '2018mbusasalesjan', 2018, 'January', 125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesfeb': [1, '2018mbusasalesfeb', 2018, 'February', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesmar': [2, '2018mbusasalesmar', 2018, 'March', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesapr': [3, '2018mbusasalesapr', 2018, 'April', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesmay': [4, '2018mbusasalesmay', 2018, 'May', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesjun': [5, '2018mbusasalesjun', 2018, 'June', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesjul': [6, '2018mbusasalesjul', 2018, 'July', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesaug': [7, '2018mbusasalesaug', 2018, 'August', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalessep': [8, '2018mbusasalessep', 2018, 'September', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesoct': [9, '2018mbusasalesoct', 2018, 'October', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesnov': [10, '2018mbusasalesnov', 2018, 'November', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             '2018mbusasalesdec': [11, '2018mbusasalesdec', 2018, 'December', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

datos_sales_mbusa = pd.read_csv('mbusasales.csv', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')
cols = [''] + list(datos_sales_mbusa)
update = pd.DataFrame(list(data_dict.values()), columns=cols).set_index('')
res = pd.concat((datos_sales_mbusa, update))
res.drop_duplicates(subset="indice", keep='last', inplace=True)
res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
res.to_csv('mbusasales.csv',  encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta,lo que hice antes de generar el diccionario fue crear las claves que estarían en el, y verificar que estas no existieran en el archivo csv, en caso de que existieran, entonces no permitiria crear el diccionario, de lo contrario este se crearía y se almacenaria en el archivo csv. Aclaro que no utilizo motores de base de datos ya que el programa es local y como lo voy a usar en una pc de una empresa no quiero generar estos motores que luego la gente de IT interpreta como que estoy tratando de hacer algo indebido en la red.

Comment: voy a revisar PEP8, como sugieren, no lo he hecho a fondo ya que quiero avanzar en el programa aunque se que esto me puede dificultar el camino, pero consideraré la sugerencia. gracias